# How do I avoid a parameter error when running the report from the MainForm?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I created a `MainSubForm` with a combobox (name = cboMedName, query = MedicationLookupQuery) and *Run Button* that points to a report (name = MedicationsPatientsReport, query = MedicationsPatientsQuery).

When I run the reports directly from `MainSubForm`, they run perfectly. The report pulls up the results showing the specific medication chosen.

I placed the `MainSubForm` into the `MainForm`. When I run the reports from there, I get a parameter error: "Forms!MainSubForm!cboMedName".

How do I avoid this error when running the report from the `MainForm`?

I know it has to do with the [Criteria syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxMg3.png)? or Control Source?

Answer (score 0):

The combobox is now in the subform, thus:

```
Forms!MainForm!NameOfSubformControlHoldingMainSubForm.Form!cboMedName
```

Here, adjust `NameOfSubformControlHoldingMainSubForm` to the name of this.